# 3rd level in menu always on the very top

Tags: css, menu, navigation, position

working on an old project when third level menu is always float for the first item in the menu 
Attached css to the ul is

```
#main.container > .row.nav > .span10 > nav.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background-color: #BFD0CA;
}
```

changing display to block doesn't help and ruines the 2nd level menu 
how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your html ? Also do not use margin on an absolute element, use top and left.

Answer (score 1):

add `left: 0; top: 0` value to your class. and don't forget to give the second level `li { position: relative }` and don't use `margin` on position absolute elements.

```
#main.container > .row.nav > .span10 > nav.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background-color: #BFD0CA;
} 

#main.container > .row.nav > .span10 > nav.menu > ul > li > 
ul > li { 
    position: relative; 
    ... 
} 
//or if this already has absolute, it doesn't matter.
```

Comment: The second level li can also be in position absolute (depending of the needs).

Comment: yeah read the comment at the end of the code :) it probably has, cuz it seems to work with the second level menu!

Comment: well either you give us a fiddle to play with, or at least a link to your page where we can try some things out.

Comment: http://www.d32.osstf.ca/Default.aspx?DN=88966b69-ca19-4651-8840-117ff2f8242a ? this? it works there

Comment: not that one, working on local environment, will c if I can put something together .. Thanks

Comment: fixed it, in the :hover, removed the top and added margin-top